# input onChange not triggered on file submit in React

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I have an input component in React that is supposed to trigger a custom `handleSubmit` function once a user uploads a file:

```
function PhotoInput({ enableInput }) {
    const inputStyle = {
        display: 'none'
    };

    const handleSubmit = (event) => {
        console.log("Uploading file...")
        // putToS3Bucket(event.target.files[0], '/upload')
    };

    if (enableInput) {
        console.log("logged")
        return (
            <input
                id="file-input"
                type="file"
                style={inputStyle}
                accept="image/*"
                onChange={handleSubmit}
            />
        );
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}

function PhotoPopover({ width, open, handlePhotoClickClose, enableInput, anchorRef }) {
    const navigate = useNavigate();
    

    return (
        <>
            <MenuPopover
                open={open}
                onClose={handlePhotoClickClose}
                anchorEl={anchorRef.current}
                sx={{ width: { width } }}
            >
                <label for="file-input">
                    <MenuItem
                        onClick={handlePhotoClickClose}
                        sx={{ typography: 'body2', py: 1, px: 2.5 }}
                    >
                        <Iconify
                            icon='eva:settings-2-fill'
                            sx={{
                                mr: 2,
                                width: 24,
                                height: 24
                            }}
                        />
                        Change Profile Photo
                    </MenuItem>
                </label>
                <PhotoInput enableInput={enableInput} />
            </MenuPopover>
        </>
    );
}
```

As you can see, this input is wrapped by a `MenuItem` component from Material. When I click on this `MenuItem`, a file uploading dialogue appears, but when I choose the file to upload, `handleSubmit` is not triggered (ie. I don't see "Uploading file..." in the console).

I'm really not sure why this is. I also tried it in a [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/wizardly-wave-t4v23h?file=/src/App.js) and it works there, but I don't see the difference between that and this code. Would someone be able to point me in the right direction?

Comment: Being that it works in the sandbox, it's probably related to some weird Material management of events, since you are using the label for event delegation, I'd try to get it out of material components and see if it gets fixed, this way you are going to isolate the problematic Component.

Comment: Seems like I should be able to use it with Material components: https://codesandbox.io/s/wizardly-wave-t4v23h?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 1):

In React, an `input type="file"` is always an uncontrolled component. You should use the File API to get information about the files uploaded. See [The file input Tag](https://reactjs.org/docs/uncontrolled-components.html#the-file-input-tag).

```
function PhotoInput({ enableInput }) {
  const fileInput = useRef(); /* create a ref*/
  const inputStyle = {
    display: 'none',
  };

  const handleSubmit = () => {
    event.preventDefault();
    /* get current files using ref */
    console.log('Uploading file...', fileInput.current.files[0].name);
  };

  if (enableInput) {
    return (
      <input
        id="file-input"
        type="file"
        style={inputStyle}
        ref={fileInput} /* add ref*/
        accept="image/*"
        onChange={handleSubmit}
      />
    );
  } else {
    return null;
  }
}
```

[Working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-dkv8sh)

Comment: Hm, but if this were the case, why would the sandbox work?

Comment: I don't understand your question, answer updated with working example, https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-dkv8sh

Comment: I created a Sandbox (https://codesandbox.io/s/wizardly-wave-t4v23h?file=/src/App.js) based on my original code and it seems to work fine without refs

Comment: yes, since it is an uncontrolled component you need to get value using ref.

Answer (score -1):

You should change the format of the function call, i.e.:

```
onChange={(e) => handleSubmit(e)}
```

Comment: Didn't seem to help, unfortunately